# what is the html tag used for?

Tags: html

Hello I am trying to write a report on html standards and I cannot for the life of me find any information on the html tag other than "its good standards" my question is why is this needed? and what if anything happens if you omit it from a document, assuming that I am working with a strict doctype. If you also know where I might find good information/arguments for and against the html tag that would be brilliant, thanks for all the help. i am working on a tutorial type website similar to the w3schools but a closed of system for students who are brand new to html so i am trying to get content together, get reading material etc in order to make this on-line system the best it can be really.

Answer (score 4):

An HTML document has to have a root node. That root node has to be an HTML element.

The specification allows for the start tag for the html element to be omitted (the presence of the element can be implied so you don't need to be specific about it.)

However, if you don't have an HTML tag, then you can't have any attributes on it. If you can't have attributes, you can't have a `lang` attribute. If you can't have a `lang` attribute then clients have to determine the language of the document by guess-work.

This can, especially if multiple languages are used in a document, cause issues such as the page showing up in different sets of search results (this document appears to be French so let's not rank it highly for an English speaker) and incorrect pronunciation guides being selected by screen readers.

There are a few other attributes that can appear on `html` tags, but that is probably the one with the most consequences for not being included. Others that could have an impact include `class` and `id` which could be used to style pages, that share a style sheet, differently.

In short: The HTML tag is only useful for the attributes you can attach to it.

Answer (score 3):

To tell the browser that it is the start and end of a html document

Comment: um I see I thought there would be more to it that that, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It marks the beginning or end of an html document.

Answer (score 3):

The SGML syntax (from which HTML derives) states that there should be only one top-most element in a document: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language#Syntax

There's no arguing whether it is needed or not: if your document doesn't have an `<html>` tag, then it's not an HTML document, pretty much like a Ferrari without a Ferrari logo isn't a Ferrari (sorry for the obligatory car analogy).

Omitting the `<html>` tag will most likely result in applications not processing your document properly; some browsers such as IE6 may attempt to find a workaround by adding missing tags to an incomplete HTML document, but globally; it would result in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Thanks this was what i was looking for thank you. and i like the car analogy it can be sued for anything lol

Comment: "There's no arguing whether it is needed or not" — yes there is. "if your document doesn't have an `<html>` tag, then it's not an HTML document" — The DTD says the start tag may be omitted. Tags are not elements.

Comment: @Quentin you learn something everyday... indeed the DTD says so, even though it contradicts SGML syntax: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-HTML though I'm not sure why you'd want to omit it.

Comment: @LâmTranDuy — How does it contradict SGML syntax?

Comment: @Quentin — Well if the `<html>` tag isn't an element then what is it? How should the text "An SGML document may have [...] the instance itself, containing one top-most element and its contents" be interpreted then? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: @LâmTranDuy — It is a tag. An element is what the parser constructs when it parses the tag … or when it parses a different tag which the DTD says cannot exist unless it is inside an element with a start tag that may be omitted.

Comment: @Quentin — Ok, so if I get it correctly, the parser will create the html element whether or not the html tag is present in the document? Just like it would add tbody elements to the DOM even if you don't mention them in the html document? I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It tells the browser that is a HTML document.  It is also the root `HTML` node. You should always include it in your HTML file and never omit it (Even if the browser renders the page correctly).

You can check if your HTML document is valid by validating it via:

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: um I see I thought there would be more to it that that, like if you don't include it elements wont render right etc, thanks for the help.